# Running a meteor.js application forever

Tags: meteor

I have a personal localhost meteor application running on my laptop which silently stops running every time the computer goes to sleep. The way I run it simply using the "meteor" command, after which i background and disown the process and close terminal.

Is there a way to prevent the app from stopping, to have it run forever on my machine unless i explicitly close it?

Comment: did you try meteor-up. may be a overkill https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a server daemon for your application in the same way you'd do on a production server. There are several ways to do this, probably the easiest one is to use [demeteorizer](https://github.com/onmodulus/demeteorizer) to create a plain Node.js program with your app, and then run it with [forever](https://www.npmjs.org/package/forever).